# Hidden ASP.NET textbox values not working jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, textbox, textinput

I have an ASPX page where in I need to set the value of "FirstName" with "YourName". Both are textboxes. "YourName" is set with visible=false on the page. Problem is Jquery works only `visible=true`.

My goal is to set Firstname with Yourname with the condition that YourName has `visible=false`.

Here are the details

```
<asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="fnameTextBox" />
<asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="ynameTextBox" visible="false" />

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('input:text[id*=fnameTextBox]').val($('input:text[id*=ynameTextBox]').val());
    });
</script>
```

I can store the value in  'ynametextbox' to some other type or variable but I don't know how to reference in Jquery (if possible).

Comment: If you are not going to show this textbox to the user at all, you should use a HiddenField.

Comment: `Visible=false` means no rendered html at all for that control, then it exists only on serverside.

Comment: @HanletEscaño: Can you provide example with HiddenField?

Comment: @NewCoder I have created an example for you using Asp.net HiddenField control.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the example with the `HiddenField` as requested:

Javascript:

```
<script src="Scripts/jquery-1.4.1.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#<%=fnameTextBox.ClientID %>').val($('#<%=hiddenTextYourName.ClientID %>').val());
    });
</script>
```

HTML

```
<asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="fnameTextBox" />
<asp:HiddenField runat="server" ID="hiddenTextYourName" Value="Hanlet" />
```

Hidden field is not visible to the user of course, but beware because they can still see the value in the HTML.

Good luck..

Answer (score 1):

This is what Control objects' ClientID property is for.  This gives you the javascript-accessible ID you would use in jQuery.  Reference would look something like this:

```
$(<%=fnameTextBox.ClientID%>)
```

Keep in mind that when you set Visible="false" on an ASP.NET server control, it is NOT rendered to the HTML output at all, so you will not be able to access it in javascript.  Hide it using CSS properties or place it in a hidden div.

Comment: I have tried wrapping it with hidden DIV but no success. Can you explain more on how to use ClientID such that I can incorporate in my code?

Answer (score 1):

when we write visible = "false", it will not render in the html. So, javascript is not able to get that element.
 instead try style="visibility:hidden;"

```
<asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="fnameTextBox" />
  <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="ynameTextBox" Text="hello" style="visibility:hidden;" />
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('input:text[id*=fnameTextBox]').val($('input:text[id*=ynameTextBox]').val());
    });
</script>
```